# Check object from one Arraylist exists in another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking for some optimised solution as I could not find, I have two ArrayList of custom object. I want to check if specific value of one arrayList exists in another.

Here is my code

```
protected void updateDb(HashSet<allDataProperty> set){

    if(set != null)
    list = new ArrayList<allDataProperty>(set);

    nt = ny.getAllData();
    if(nt.size() > 0) {
        for (allData e1 : nt) {
            for (allData e2 : list) {
                if (e1.type.equals("Student") && e2.type.equals("Student")) {
                    if (!(e1.section.equals(e2.section))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not FOUND" + e1.section + "dddd" + e2.section);
                    }
                } else if (e1.type.equals("Emp") && e2.type.equals("Emp")) {
                    if (!(e1.cat == (e2.cat))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not" + e1.cat + "Category" + e2.cat);
                    }
                } else if (e1.type.equals("Other") && e2.type.equals("Other")) {
                    if (!(e1.cls.equals(e2.cls))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not");
                    }
                } else if (e1.type.equals("OutSider") && e2.type.equals("OutSider")) {
                    if (!(e1.ran_code == (e2.ran_code))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not " + e1.ran_code + "Generated" + e2.ran_code);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

So, the idea is to find if any value from ArrayList list exists in the list returned from Database which is ArrayList nt based on some specific conditions as I have made in code above.

Is there any easier way or clean way to do it. Thanks for help

Comment: Could you not use ArrayList.contains(Object) here? See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: You mean without traversing ArrayList, like nt.contains(list.get(i).section ?

Comment: Does `allDataProperty` override `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: you could use a map of `<String, allDataProperty>` (the String being `e1.type`)

Comment: you could use a map of `<String, allDataProperty>` (the String being `e1.type`)

Comment: not an android question.  I'm just saying

Comment: Would u please post what do you have in `allDataProperty` class

Comment: Yup. Just a. Contains should sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
for(CustomObject a:listA){
    if(listB.contains(a)){
         Log.i("Activity","Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: OP would also need to implement `equals()` in `CustomObject` - otherwise it would default to `Object.equals()` (which may not be the desired behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

A quick comparison of the types would make it fly faster.  Storing the types in variables would make it fly faster.  I would do this at a higher level in the database.

```
if(nt.size() > 0) {
    for (allData e1 : nt) {
                string mType1 = e1.type;
        for (allData e2 : list) {
                string mType2 = e2.type
            //quick compare equal
            if (mType1 == mType2) {
                if (mType1.equals("Student")) {
                    if (!(e1.section.equals(e2.section))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not FOUND" + e1.section + "dddd" + e2.section);
                    }
                } else if (mType1.equals("Emp") {
                    if (!(e1.cat == (e2.cat))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not" + e1.cat + "Category" + e2.cat);
                    }
                } else if (mType1.equals("Other") {
                    if (!(e1.cls.equals(e2.cls))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not");
                    }
                } else if (mType1.equals("OutSider") {
                    if (!(e1.ran_code == (e2.ran_code))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FOUND Not " + e1.ran_code + "Generated" + e2.ran_code);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have passed your set as a HashSet, you can make use of the lookup benefits a HashSet can provide - the HashSet contains() method runs in O(1) or constant time. In contrast, the ArrayList contains() method requires linear time, or O(n) to run. As far as I know, you can do this by defining an allData.equals(allDataProperty a) method, similar to the following:

```
//in allData class
Boolean equals(allDataProperty a) {
    if (e1.type.equals("Student") && e2.type.equals("Student")) {
         if (e1.section.equals(e2.section)) {
             return true;
         }
    } else if (e1.type.equals("Emp") && e2.type.equals("Emp")) {
         if (e1.cat == (e2.cat)) {
             return true;
         }
    } else if (e1.type.equals("Other") && e2.type.equals("Other")) {
        if (e1.cls.equals(e2.cls)) {
             return true;
        }
    } else if (e1.type.equals("OutSider") && e2.type.equals("OutSider")) {
        if (!(e1.ran_code == (e2.ran_code))) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then your updateDb function could look something like this:
    protected void updateDb(HashSet set){

```
    if(set != null) {

    for(allData e1 : nt) {
        if(set.contains(e1)) {
            Log.d("FOUND", e1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP never once said anything about speed efficiency. Just a 'cleaner' way of doing it.